# Forms all inputs access in jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make jquery plugin for form validation (for learning). In this form i am unable to get all form fields which has class name "required". The code is following:

```
(function( $ ) {

$.fn.kValidation =  function() {     

    this.on("submit", function (event ) {

        event.preventDefault();

        $(this + " .required").each( function () {

\\this loop dont get all form inputs which has class "required"

            alert();
        })

}( jQuery ));
```

HTML is following:

```
<form id="fo">
<input class="required" data-kvLimit="min:5 max:200" data-kvType="numeric" /><br>
<input class="required" data-kvLimit="min:5 max:200" data-kvType="string" /><br>
<input class="required" data-kvType="email" /><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I am calling plugin this way

```
$("form").kValidation();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `context` parameter of `jQuery()` to `this` : `form` element. Note also, missing closing `})` at `.on()`, and closing `}` at `$.fn.kValidation`

```
  $(function() {
    (function($) {
      $.fn.kValidation = function() {
        this.on("submit", function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          $(" .required", this).each(function() {
            console.log(this)
          })
        })
      }
    }(jQuery));

    $("form").kValidation();

  });
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/DqX44H5p9HEA3P5tfZMC?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for $(".required", this) its even better

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$(this + " .required")
```

To

```
$(this).find('.required')
```

The first one is mistaken syntax. It effectively tries to concatenate the jQuery reference (an object) to the form element, with the string ".required".